# Sobolev Inequality for $u \in W_{0}^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, cauchy-sequences

For $1\leq p<n$ and $$p^{*}:=\frac{np}{n-p},$$ one can prove that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $$\|u\|_{L^{p^{*}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\leq c\|\nabla u\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}$$ for all $u\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. This is known as the Sobolev-Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality.

I was trying to prove that this must also hold for all $u\in W_{0}^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. The space $W_{0}^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is the $\|\cdot\|_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}$-closure of $C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ in the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, where $\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^{p}:=\|u\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^{p}+\|\nabla u\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^{p}$.

To do so, I tried to use a density argument: If $u\in W_{0}^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, then there exists a sequence $(u_{k})$ in $C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that $\|u_{k}-u\|_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\to0$. Using the Sobolev-Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality and the definition of $\|\cdot\|_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}$, we see that $$\|u_{k}-u_{l}\|_{L^{p^{*}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\leq c\|\nabla(u_{k}-u_{l})\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\leq c\|u_{k}-u_{l}\|_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}$$ for all $k,l\geq1$. So $(u_{k})$ is Cauchy in the Banach space $L^{p^{*}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and therefore convergent. Thus there is a $\tilde{u}\in L^{p^{*}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that $\|u_{k}-\tilde{u}\|_{L^{p^{*}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\to0$.

I don't know how to finish the argument from here. Can we for example conclude that $\tilde{u}=u$ a.e.? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $u_k\to u$ in $W^{1,p}\subset L^1_{loc}$ ($L^1$ when restricted to compact subsets of $\mathbb R^n$)  and $u_k\to \tilde u$ in $L^{p^*} \subset L^1_{loc}$, it follows that $u=\tilde u$. So $u=\tilde u\in L^{p^*}\cap W^{1,p}$.

Furthermore, if $(X,\|\cdot\|_X)$ is any normed space, then by rearranging the triangle inequality
$\|u+v\|_X \le \|u\|_X + \|v\|_X$
we obtain
$$ |\|u\|_X-\|v\|_X| \le \|u-v\|_X$$
Applying this to our Banach spaces,
$$\|u_k\|_{L^{p^*}} \to \|u\|_{L^{p^*}} ,\quad \|\nabla u_k \|_{L^p} \to \|\nabla u\|_{L^p}$$

Thus we may pass to the limit in the norm inequality.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can you elaborate on why $\tilde{u}=u$ a.e.? Since $u_{k}\to u$ in the $W^{1,p}$-topology and $u_{k}\to \tilde{u}$ in the $L^{p^{*}}$ topology, I'm not sure that it is sufficient to say that $W^{1,p}\subset L_{\text{loc}}^{1}$ and $L^{p^{*}}\subset L_{\text{loc}}^{1}$, since this inclusion is set-theoretic and not in a 'topological way'. Hence the uniqueness-of-limits-argument cannot be used. (I think)

Comment: @Calculix the second part has a bug...but the first part is kosher because this means that they are well defined as $L^1(K)$ functions, so must agree on $K$ (a.e., of course)  by uniqueness of limits in $L^1(K)$, and then $K$ is arbitrary

Comment: To conclude that $u=\tilde{u}$ by using the uniqueness of limits, the sequence $(u_{k})$ must converge to $u$ and $\tilde{u}$ in the same topology, which is not the case, I think.

Comment: @Calculix they converge in the topology of $L^1(K)$. Suppose the two limits were different; then there would exist some $K$ such that their restrictions to $K$ were not equal. Here they are $L^1(K)$, and the convergence in $L^1(K)$ is contradicted. The constant in $\|u_k - u\|_{L^1(K)} \le C_K \|u_k-u\|_X $  where $X=L^q$ or $W^{1,q}$ explodes as $K\to \mathbb R^n$ but you do the argument for each fixed $K$

Comment: @Calculix I have fixed the second part, it is much simpler than whatever I had before (sorry!) Are you still not convinced re the first part?

Comment: Perhaps the simplest argument to see why $u=\tilde u$ a.e. is to recall that if a function sequence converges in some $L_p$ then a subsequence converges a.e.

Comment: @MartinVäth works too! Thanks for the input

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks again! But one minor issue is the righthand side of the inequality, since $\|\nabla \cdot\|_{L^{p}}$ is not the norm on our Banach space. It is $\|\cdot\|_{W^{1,p}}$.

Comment: well its an equivalent norm but why did you bother adding the $L^p$ norm?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Because that was the definition in the book I’m using.

Comment: @Calculix but you said you wanted to SGN inequality which has the norm of the gradient?